# Applying update to dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this dynamic sql statement:

```
  TRUNCATE TABLE ' + @FirstTableSchemaName + '.' + @FirstTableName + '
   INSERT INTO  ' + @FirstTableSchemaName + '.' + @FirstTableName + '
   ( 
    action,
    ' + @ListColumn + '
   )
   SELECT action, 
    ' + @ListColumn + '
   FROM
   (
    MERGE INTO ' + @SecondTableSchemaName + '.' + @FirstTableName + ' AS TARGET
```

---

I need to apply an update to the first table before the select action statement. My update would look like this:

```
Update FirsttableName 
set ColumnName = COALESCE(b.column, a.column)
from FirsttableName a
LEFT JOIN TableName b ON a.ColumnName = b.ColumnName
```

Can someone please provide examples of what this should look like?

Comment: Do the 2 tables have the same columns? If they don't, how do you know which columns maps to which? Will you be supplying a mapping dataset?

Comment: Why do you need to truncate a table, then insert into it and immediately update it? Why not insert the correct data to begin with? Fix your insert statement.

Comment: @SeanLange  the truncate is there because it is an automated process that deletes the data out of the table every time the job runs

Comment: Right I assumed you truncated it to remove the previous data. But why do you need to insert into it and then immediately update it? Just insert the correct data.

Comment: And really we need more details to be able to answer this. See [here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some ideas of what you should post.